# ejabberd: Subscribe user to room, return room name as response

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm using Strophe.js together with the MUC plugin. I'm connected as 'agent' in the browser and I used an external python script to add the 'agent' to a room. This is how the app will work, the backend will add the connected user to certain rooms, but the front-end needs to know where to send messages.

```
def add_user_to_room(user_name, room_name):
    command = 'subscribe_room'
    url = '{}/{}/{}'.format(base_url, api, command)

    data = {
        "user": add_host(user_name)+'/180062769060911144972260',
        "nick": add_host(user_name),
        "room": room_name + '@' + muc_service,
        "nodes": "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages,urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations,urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subscribers"
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    print('Got result code {} with text {}'.format(response.status_code, response.text))
    return response.status_code, response.text
```

This is the response I get in the socket:

```
<message xmlns='jabber:client' to='agent@chat.domain.com/6665193359253278721998' from='agent@chat.domain.com'>
  <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
    <items node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subscribers'>
      <item id='8698546583380897793'>
        <subscribe jid='agent@chat.domain.com' nick='agent@chat.domain.com' xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0'/>
      </item>
    </items>
  </event>
</message>
```

Is there a way to get the room name in the browser when the external script adds the user to a certain room?

Comment: When I execute the subscribe_room command, the online user does not get any packet. Where or how do you get that response?

Comment: No idea, really new at this, but I do have the pubsub plugin installed on both ends.